# Dual booting Manjaro kde with windows 10

Tags: linux, partitioning, arch-linux, kde, manjaro

I want to dual boot my laptop(win 10 preinstalled) with Manjaro-kde plasma, I only have 512gb ssd , already divided into two(C=276gb & D=200gb). How much free space should I leave in Windows C drive and the new partition where linux is going to be installed respectively. And which should I partition , the existing C or D drive  for the new linux drive? [ Note: the C drive has 201gb free out of 276gb with windows and some software installed on it.]

Answer (score 0):

Take note that Windows 10 can grow to pretty big size over time, especially if you install games or large software. Mine takes up 90GB without games and without counting the swap file (122 total).

My C partition is 150GB with 27GB free. My advice is to prepare for the worst, better safe than sorry. 150GB C partition should be enough for most people in my opinion.

You didn't mention how much free space you have on D partition, it might make your decision simpler.

Also keep in mind that in 90% of the cases a virtual machine might be sufficient and less of a hassle.